# Segmented Control, changing a UIImageView (Programmatically) Swift 4/5

Tags: ios, swift

I've included the code to my segmented control and UIImageView. Any help would be great, thanks.

```
let segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl = {
        let sc = UISegmentedControl(items: ["Login", "Register"])
        sc.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        sc.tintColor = UIColor.white
        sc.selectedSegmentIndex = 0

        sc.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleSegmentedControlChange), for: .valueChanged)
        return sc
    }()
```

```
// profile pic
    lazy var picture: UIImageView = {
        var pic = UIImageView()
        if segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
            pic.image = UIImage(named: "Logo")
        } else {
            pic.image = UIImage(named: "Profile")

            let mytapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSelectProfileImageView))
            mytapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
            pic.addGestureRecognizer(mytapGestureRecognizer)
            pic.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        }
        pic.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        pic.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        return pic
    }()
```

The picture is supposed to change and enable the touch gesture but neither of them works.

Answer (score 0):

Move the If-else block to handleSegmentedControlChange selector.

Comment: Thank you that worked. But why wouldn't what I tried to do work?

Comment: This is because the action for segment selection can be handled only in the segment Control selector .

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Create a `@objc func` that receive as a parameter `(_ sender: UISegmentedControl)` , for example:

```
@objc func segmentedControlChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl)
```

**2)** After create your UISegmentedControl, use addTarget, like this:

```
segmentedControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(segmentedControlChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
```

**3)** In the func that you created, implement the corresponding logic:

```
  @objc func segmentedControlChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
         if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
            pic.image = UIImage(named: "Logo") 
            // Also, if you want to resize your image view after set the new image, call sizeToFit() func here. 
         } else {
            pic.image = UIImage(named: "Profile")
            // And here. 
  }
}
```